# Bounding integral for a function in $L_1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider $(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{B}, \lambda) $If $f$ is non-negative and in $L_1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{B}, \lambda)$ is it true that for some $\alpha < -1$ $$ \int_{[1,\infty)} f d\lambda \leq \int_{[1,\infty)} x^\alpha $$
I was thinking about this but was not sure on a rigorous proof, if it is even true that is.

Comment: This can't be true. $x\mapsto x^\alpha$ is integrable and so is $x\mapsto M x^\alpha$ for any $M$.

Comment: so can we bound by the integral of the latter mapping then? you should elaborate

Comment: If $f$ is in $L^1$, then there is a $C\geq 0$ such that $\int_{[1,\infty)}f\,\mathrm d\lambda \leq C$. On the other hand, $x\mapsto x^{\alpha}\in L^1$ for any $\alpha<-1$. So there is an $M_\alpha\geq 0$ such that $\int_{[1,\infty)}x^\alpha\,\mathrm d\lambda\leq M_\alpha$. In other words, for any $C\geq 0$ you want to find an $\alpha<-1$ such that $C\leq\int x^\alpha\,\mathrm d\lambda$. But does would mean that $\int x^\alpha\,\mathrm d\lambda$ is unbound, contradicting the fact that $x\mapsto x^\alpha\in L^1$, no?

Comment: thanks that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of contradiction, assume there exists a function $f^*\in L^1([1,\infty))$ such that
$$\int_{[1,\infty)} fd\lambda\le \int_{[1,\infty)} f^*d\lambda \tag1 $$
for all $f\in L^1([1,\infty))$. Note that since (e.g.) $x\mapsto x^{-2}\in  L^1([1,\infty))$, this implies
$$ \int_{[1,\infty)} f^*d\lambda \ge \int_{[1,\infty)} x^{-2}\ d\lambda(x)>0 \tag 2 $$

But now consider $f\equiv 2f^*$ : clearly $f\in L^1([1,\infty))$ as multiplying by a scalar doesn't affect integrability. Furthemore, because we assumed that $(1)$ is true we get
$$ \int_{[1,\infty)} fd\lambda:=  \int_{[1,\infty)} 2f^*d\lambda = 2\int_{[1,\infty)} f^*d\lambda\le \int_{[1,\infty)} f^*d\lambda\tag 3  $$
Substracting $\int_{[1,\infty)} f^*d\lambda $ from both sides of the inequality $(3)$ we find
$$\int_{[1,\infty)} f^*d\lambda \le 0 \tag 4 $$
This is a contradiction with $(2)$. Hence such a function $f^*$ can't exist.